# How to prioritize a 802.11ac over 802.11n?

Tags: wi-fi, samsung-galaxy-s-9

I have (at the office and at home) WiFi APs which serve 802.11n and 802.11ac over the same SSID.

My Galaxy S9+ never connects to the 5 GHz network on these SSIDs. I thought that this may be because the signal strength which is too low on the 5 GHz network and the 2 GHz looks more promising.

I created a 802.11ac-only SSID and connected my phone and tested for bandwidth which was ~90 Mbps, even in the most remote part of my home.

This probably means that the algorithm which selects the standard to use is less than optimal and I would like to help it by prioritizing the 802.11ac signal on a dual-standard SSID. **Is this something which is configurable a way or another on Android (specifically Oreo on an S9+)?**

Comment: This is a function of the router, as the answer below states it is not controlled by the phone. If you want the phone to "control" this, you could need to have a unique SSID for each network type you would connect to (or at least a unique one for 802.11ac). Or if you device is cable, to limit the phone to only use 802.11ac by disabling other bands (not likely in modern devices).

Answer (score 2):

When the SSID is shared, the access point is responsible for band steering.

> Dual band operation with Band Steering detects clients capable of 5
>   GHz operation and steers them to that frequency which leaves the more
>   crowded 2.4 GHz band available for legacy clients.
>   *— [Source](https://documentation.meraki.com/MR/Radio_Settings/Band_Steering_Overview)*

Enable band steering in your WiFi controller.